# Image not being displayed in the browser when trying to load it via XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have this in the data.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TVchannel> //This is the root element that consists of IT, PTG and HR tv

    <monthname month="September">  

        <channelname name="IT">  
            <title>Welcome to IT TV</title> 
        <images>
        <image path="image1.png"/>
        <image path="image2.png"/>
        </images>
        </channelname>

        <channelname name="PTG">
            <title>Welcome to PTG TV</title>
        <images>
        <image path="image3.jpeg"/>
        <image path="image4.jpeg"/>
        </images>
              </channelname>

        <channelname name="HR">
            <title>Welcome to HR TV</title> 
        <images>
        <image path="image5.jpeg"/>
        <image path="image6.jpeg"/>
        </images>   
        </channelname>

    </monthname>

    <monthname month="October"> //the view for a different month

        <channelname name="IT">
            <title>Welcome to IT TV</title>   
        </channelname>

        <channelname name="PTG">
            <title>Welcome to PTG TV</title>    
        </channelname>

        <channelname name="HR">
            <title>Welcome to HR TV</title>         
        </channelname>

    </monthname>

</TVchannel>
```

I have this php file which uses simplexml to load this data.xml and iterate to get each image.

```
<?php
    $picture_container = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
    $title_bar = $picture_container->{'monthname'}[0]->{'channelname'}[0]->title;
    echo $title_bar;

header("content-type: image/png");
    foreach($picture_container->{'monthname'}[0]->{'channelname'}[0]->images->image as $iterator)
     {  
        echo '<img src="'.$iterator['path'].'"/>';      

    }

?>
```

The browser does not show me any error but displays an empty icon. (see pic)
[image: The browser does not show me any error but show an empty icon(see pic).The weird concentric rectangles!!!]

Please help me..Thanks

Comment: For me this is printing on browser `Welcome to IT TV<img src="image1.png"/><img src="image2.png"/>`

Comment: You're generating an HTML with `img` tags. The content type is wrong and you have output before it. Validate the generated HTML output in the source view/developer tools of your browser. Make sure that the image is available from the browser on the provided URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're targeting the attribute *path*, the use `->attributes()` :)

```
echo $iterator->attributes()->path;
```

Comment: I replaced  echo '<img src="'.$iterator['path'].'"/>'; with echo '<img src="'.$iterator->attributes()->path.'"/>';   It still does not work

Comment: @AakashTiwari just make sure the path is correct, of course you need to point it out to the correct directory, if its in the same directory, then `image5.jpeg` should be enough, just make sure the file is readable

Answer (score -2):

Resolved
write this in foreach loop

```
echo '<img src="'.$iterator['path'].'" height="100"; "width="100" ;>';
```

Comment: How ; works at the end of img tag? this is wrong syntax